# Debug custom sandbox workflow action

Tags: sandbox-solution

How to debug the custom sandbox workflow actions in VS2010?

The sandbox workflow actions created following the steps in 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798499.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The only way I've found to do accomplish this is through the log files in c:\program files\common files\microsoft shared\web server extensions\14\logs

Answer (score 0):

To debug a sandboxed solution you have to attach to Process to the SPUCWorkerProcess.exe assembly. But this does not always work.